# React Router and Links all directing to the same page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the list of react Links is all just loading the error page.  Could anyone advise please? its almost a direct copy of a previous project that worked perfectly.

Router Set up

```
function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path = '/'>
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path = "*">
        <Error />
      </Route>
      <Route path = '/about'>
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path = '/contact'>
        <Contact />
      </Route>
      <Route path = '/deckbuilder'>
        <DeckBuilder />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Links on Home Page

```
export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Home Page </h1>
            <Link to = '/contact'>
                Contact
            </Link>
            <Link to = '/about'>
                about
            </Link>
            <Link to = '*'>
                Error
            </Link>
            <Link to = '/deckbuilder'>
                Deck
            </Link>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: try move the error route at the end. iirc react router redirect to the first one that matches so, in this case, will always be error

Comment: worked, strange as this didnt happen on my last project at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use react router like this and put error component at last, this is correct syntax:

```
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path='/sign' component={Sign} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add some more information to the @Shivam Jha answer.

> worked, strange as this didnt happen on my last project at all

There's no way to work this on previous project if your router configuration is same like above. This issue in not specific to the React router. Even when developing backend applications this can happen.

The thing which make the problem is that start(*) mark. This mark represent any value. By that mean, the second router declartion of your code, i.e route for `<Error />` triggered every time when the url is match to *.
That mean,

1. `/abcd`
2. `/sign`
3. `/login`

All of the above paths match to `*`. So React router does not even check the next router declarations. It simply route to the `<Error />` page. So as the solution, you should always declare static routes at the top of the configuration while things like `*`, `:id` defined at bottom

Another case is, If you have, two routes as

1. `abcd.com/posts`
2. `abcd.com/:id`

then If you defined the `abcd.com/:id` above the `abcd.com/posts`then you will never able to send a request to the `/posts` endpoint. This is not only specific to React router. Even when doing backend development, you have to be aware of this.